# Swift: Generics with callbacks

Tags: swift, generics, callback

I'm trying to keep a Dictionary of callbacks in which the callback could contain a parameter that is of a base class type, then I could call the callback with any derived type. When I try to do it I get a compile error. I come from a C++/C# background so I'm trouble wrapping my head around how this is done in Swift.

Here's a simplified use case:

```
public func RegisterMessage<T: Message>(type: MessageType, callback: (msg: T) -> ())
{
    // ERROR: Cannot assign a value of type '(msg: T) -> ()' to a value
    //        of type '((msg: Message) -> ())?'
    MessageCallbacks[type] = callback
}

private var MessageCallbacks : [MessageType : (msg: Message) -> ()] = [:]
```

If it was compiling, here's the code I'd expected for using it:

```
RegisterMessage<SetPositionMessage>(MessageType.SetPosition, OnSetPosition)

// This would take msg's type, using it to find the callback in the
// dictionary, and then it would pass the msg into the callback function.
let msg = SetPositionMessage()
SendMessage(msg)

public func SendMessage(msg: Message)
{
    MessageCallbacks[msg.MessageType]?.(msg)
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that I have a way to designate a callback function that should be called based on a message type being sent.

Here's another code sample showing my issue. I can have a container of base types that will accept a derived type, but this doesn't work for a container of callbacks that have a base types.

```
public class BaseClass {
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
}

var Container: [BaseClass] = []
Container.append(BaseClass())
Container.append(DerivedClass())

var Callbacks: [(msg: BaseClass) -> ()] = []

func BaseCallback(msg: BaseClass) {}

func DerivedCallback(msg: DerivedClass) {}

Callbacks.append(BaseCallback)
Callbacks.append(DerivedCallback)
// ERROR! Cannot assign a value of type '(DerivedClass) -> ()' to expected argument type '(msg: BaseClass) -> ()'
```

Comment: You can downcast using:

`MessageCallbacks[type] = (callback as! (msg: Message) -> ())`

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: Great. I'll add it as an answer so you can close it off...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can downcast using:

```
MessageCallbacks[type] = (callback as! (msg: Message) -> ())
```

Comment: What if I dont want to downcast because I want to retain the derivedType to check if the response can be cast to derivedType. Would that be possible?..

Comment: If you're saying your callbacks have different return types, they would all have to derive from a common base. When you make the callback you will not lose the derived type of the response, but you will have to try and cast it back to the expected type.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me using Swift3. I get the following: Could not cast value of type '(swiftest.SetPositionMessage) -> ()' (0x10074b0d0) to '(swiftest.Message) -> ()'